# Facebook CurlException 3 No URL set

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting

FacebookApiException Object
   (

[result:protected] => Array

(
          [error_code] => 3
           [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => No URL set!
                    [type] => CurlException
                )

```
    )

[message:protected] => No URL set!
[string:private] => 
[code:protected] => 3
[file:protected] => /home5/theteci0/public_html/team/fb6/base_facebook.php
[line:protected] => 979
[trace:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home5/theteci0/public_html/team/fb6/base_facebook.php
                [line] => 911
                [function] => makeRequest
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/172535322883581_253291878141258
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [fields] => updated_time
                                [method] => GET
                                [access_token] => /*Acc_tkn*/
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home5/theteci0/public_html/team/fb6/base_facebook.php
                [line] => 878
                [function] => _oauthRequest
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => https://graph.facebook.com/172535322883581_253291878141258
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [fields] => updated_time
                                [method] => GET
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home5/theteci0/public_html/team/fb6/base_facebook.php
                [line] => 656
                [function] => _graph
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /172535322883581_253291878141258
                        [1] => GET
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [fields] => updated_time
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home5/theteci0/public_html/team/user/comments.php
                [line] => 71
                [function] => api
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Facebook Object
                                    (
                                        [appId:protected] => 
                                        [appSecret:protected] => 
                                        [user:protected] => 
                                        [signedRequest:protected] => 
                                        [state:protected] => 
                                        [accessToken:protected] => /*Acc_tkn*/
                                        [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
                                        [trustForwarded:protected] => 
                                    )

                                [1] => _graph
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => /172535322883581_253291878141258
                                [1] => GET
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [fields] => updated_time
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

I am getting this error a Lot, how to prevent it or solve it?

Answer (score 0):

by problems with IPV6 you should have included the following line in your facebook api.

```
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE] = CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4;
```

however this alternative only works with version 5.3 of php largest and Curl version > 7.10.8

solution:

```
if((phpversion()>= 5.3)){ Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE] = CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4; }
```