# Facebook SDK error during login attempt: No URL set

Tags: php, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I'm getting the following error message

> Facebook SDK returned an error: No URL set!
>
> Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'No
>   URL set!' in
>   /membri/csslab/sdk/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php:83
>
> Stack trace:
>
> 0 /membri/csslab/sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookClient.php(216): Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient->send('https://graph.f...',
>   'GET', '', Array, 60)
>
> 1 /membri/csslab/sdk/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php(277):
>   Facebook\FacebookClient->sendRequest(Object(Facebook\FacebookRequest))
>
> 2 /membri/csslab/sdk/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php(226):
>   Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client->sendRequestWithClientParams('/oauth/access_t...',
>   Array)
>
> 3 /membri/csslab/sdk/src/Facebook/Authentication/OAuth2Client.php(166):
>   Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client->requestAnAccessToken(Array)
>
> 4 /membri/csslab/sdk/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(255):
>   Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client->getAccessTokenFromCode('AQAAf_xMnFr0C7i...',
>   'http://csslab.a...')
>
> 5 /membri/csslab/login-callback.php(30):
>   Facebook\Hel in
>   /membri/csslab/sdk/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php
>   on line 83

when trying to login with Facebook credentials.

Everything works fine in local. I have properly set the domain in Facebook App.

The code I'm using is that suggested by Facebook's documentation:

```
<?php // login-callback.php
session_start();

function redirect($url, $permanent = false) {
    if (headers_sent() === false) {
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, ($permanent === true) ? 301 : 302);
    }
    exit();
}

$path = '';
$uri = 'http://xxxxx.altervista.org';
require_once $path . 'sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {

    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    // Logged in!
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
    // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
    redirect($uri . 'survey.php?token='.$_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] ,   false);
} elseif ($helper->getError()) {
    // There was an error (user probably rejected the request)
    echo '<p>Error: ' . $helper->getError();
    echo '<p>Code: ' . $helper->getErrorCode();
    echo '<p>Reason: ' . $helper->getErrorReason();
    echo '<p>Description: ' . $helper->getErrorDescription();
    exit;
}
?>
```

UPDATE:

```
 public function send($url, $method, $body, array $headers, $timeOut)
{
$this->openConnection($url, $method, $body, $headers, $timeOut);
$this->sendRequest();

if ($curlErrorCode = $this->facebookCurl->errno()) {
    throw new FacebookSDKException($this->facebookCurl->error(), $curlErrorCode);
}

// Separate the raw headers from the raw body
list($rawHeaders, $rawBody) = $this->extractResponseHeadersAndBody();

$this->closeConnection();

return new GraphRawResponse($rawHeaders, $rawBody);
}
```

Comment: check the `domain` in `facebook App`. you need to add domain what you  are using.

Comment: Thanks @Yash! In my case, the domain is http://xxxx.altervista.org, right?

Comment: right, you have to add domain name.

Comment: I set the right domain in facebook App, but I continue to get the same error message.

Comment: Have you enabled `php_curl`? Can you check if [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19597365/1627271) helps?

Comment: @choz, I saw that answer, but I don't get where I should put that line of code!

Comment: @stochazesthai Idk if it might help. But you can try before you start initializing your Facebook API. So, it'd be before `$fb = new Facebook...`

Comment: I'm getting an error: Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in ...

Comment: @stochazesthai I just noticed that you said everything worked fine in local. Then, you should start confirming on php extensions versions on your server whether it's a match with your local. IMO, there's nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0

Comment: @krishna ... what?

Comment: @Dmitry I tried. It failed. Same error.

Comment: sorry, there was bad advice. I remove them. And i'm tried run your code on my local machine with php_curl and without it. And i can't catch this exception.

Comment: But this exception should contain curl error code `throw new FacebookSDKException($this->facebookCurl->error(), $curlErrorCode);`. Can you view this code (maybe it's can help us to define problem)?

Comment: @Dmitry I updated my question providing the curl error code you were mentioning... I hope it will help...

Comment: Sorry for my English. I mean error code (numeric code) which describe error. You can get it like this `$e->getCode();`. This is numeric code, and  [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) you can find transcript for this code.

Comment: This error message typically occurs when the developer has not set a valid redirect URL in their Facebook App settings. The redirect URL is the location that the user will be directed to after they have successfully logged in with their Facebook account. This URL needs to be set in the App Dashboard under the Settings > Basic section. Make sure that the redirect URL is set correctly and that it matches the URL that the user is being directed to after the login attempt.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth helps to manage the access tokens you have to validate them

```
// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId({app-id}); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');
```

Comment: I get an error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in /membri/csslab/login-callback.php on line 50

Comment: $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but you can use a package to handle social login (fb, twitter, google, ...) you might want to look at this PHP League package and use their library instead of using the facebook SDK.

https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client

Sometimes when you're really stuck, it helps to try things from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

check your callback url or OAuth url in facebook developer panel. And be sure that you put https:// at the beginning of callback url. This is really old bug of facebook... maybe this could help...